# SQLError with dateadd function / time functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL. I am making a query with the parameters to filter out any objects that has been shipped over 6 months ago, and (after checking other variables) if it has been shipped within the past 21 days. The code will work if I keep the last line commented out (I will show you below), but when I uncomment this line, the code gives me the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've been trying things and researching, but I am still having trouble. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Code below:

```
where i.status IN ('CR','LB','OB')
and i.FGCs > 0
and i.LastShpd > CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-180,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime)
and (n.LastShpd IN ('0', '') 
     and (i.OnOrder IN ('0', '') 
     or i.LastShpd < CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-21,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime2)))
```

Comment: Why do you cast a datetime to char then back to datetime2? Especially to a much smaller length?

Comment: what is the datatype of `lastshpd`?

Comment: lastshpd is a date and time datatype

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
where i.status IN ('CR','LB','OB')
and i.FGCs > 0
and i.LastShpd > CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-180,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime) 
and (n.LastShpd IN ('0', '') -- I'm assuming error occurred in this point
     and (i.OnOrder IN ('0', '') 
     or i.LastShpd < CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,-21,GETDATE()),113) AS datetime2)))
```

try this :

```
FORMAT (n.LastShpd, 'd', 'en-US' ) in ('0','')
```

Once you use the `FORMAT`, SQL converts that values to `varchar`. Then you can apply your string conditions.

Comment: `FORMAT` may not be available depending on which version of SQL Server the asker is using. (It requires 2012+.)

Comment: Oops! I didn't think about that :(

Comment: Thank you Marin Mohanadas. My error was occurring at that exact point, and this help me find the error. I appreciate you helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Given the cast to datetime or datetime2 before comparing to i.LastShpd I am assuming the data type of i.LastShpd date related. Therefore, I think using [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) instead of DATEADD will simplify your query...

```
where i.status IN ('CR','LB','OB')
and i.FGCs > 0
and datediff(day, getdate(), i.LastShpd) < -180
and (n.LastShpd IN ('0', '') 
     and (i.OnOrder IN ('0', '') 
     or datdiff(day, getdate(), i.LastShpd) < -21))
```

Comment: I apologies, your code was correct. My error was actually with the n.LastShpd datatype. But your code is more efficient. Thank you for your help.